# Syntax error with Escaping double quotes

Tags: c#, escaping, double-quotes

```
tw.WriteLine(@" ""Air Temperature sensor "" 20," + measure + ", 24, """ + this.time.Year + "-" + this.time.Month + "-" + this.time.Day + " " + this.time.Hour + ":" + this.time.Minute + ":" + this.time.Second + "\"");
```

When I have three double quotes is call me I have *Syntax error, ',' expected* I try with four double quotes, with slash but again I have this error. I know for escaping double quotes is need two double quotes. But for my case is not working.

Comment: You should put @ before each string you want to escape double qoutes in that way. `@"" + ""` the second added string is not verbatim.

Comment: is working. Thanks. I forget for @

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you are trying to achieve, the best approach is using `string.Format`, as follows:

```
string.Format(@"""Air Temperature sensor "" 20, {0}, 24 "" {1:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}", measure, this.time);
```

You don't need to build the date taking the single properties when .NET can format it for you.

Answer (score 1):

As per msdn, you will either use @"" or escape with \"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx